# why js "onClick" Delete, does not run as instructed

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

when clicked on the button **onClick = "Delete"** instead redirects to http://localhost/example.com/?

It should show a popup delete menu, click "delete". and data is deleted.

**View button:**

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" onclick="delete_order('<?php echo $value->idorder; ?>');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="delete order"><i class="la la-trash"></i></button>
```

**Script js:**

```
function deleteBanner(id) {
    swal({
            title: "Hapus Banner ini ?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Hapus",
            cancelButtonText: "Batal",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/Design/delete_banner'); ?>",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "id": id
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#alert').html(data);
                         dataBanner();
                    }
                });
                swal("Terhapus!", "Image Terhapus", "success");
            } else {
                swal("", "", "error");
            }
        });
}
```

I am very happy and grateful if anyone can help check if there is a writing error?
or what should I fix and what's the problem!

Because I tried to check repeatedly there was no problem with writing the script.

Comment: You say it needs to run: delete_order("something") and I don't see no function like that in your js at all...  also you have not shared your whole html,  it is not part of a form right?!

Comment: you only have deleteBanner(id) in you JS ... why would this work?

Comment: sory I mean it's not a deleteBanner(id) function, but a delete_order(id) function, but with this function when the button is clicked it still directs to: ttp://localhost/example.com/? so the data is not deleted.

Comment: Let me be a little more clear: Where is the delete_order(id) function?   this: onclick="delete_order('<?php echo $value->idorder; ?>');" -- calls a function called: delete_order ... where is it? that is the code I am looking for to understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, i finally found the solution.
just add **<a href='javascript:void(0)';>** problem can be solved.